# Filtering a data frame in R when 2 conditions are met

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a large CSV file with over 4000 rows.

```
       MD HI FI 
 [1,]   7   1    1
 [2,]   7   0    1
 [3,]   4   1    1
 [4,]   3   0    11
 [5,]   9   1    0
```

I want to extract all the rows where both HI and FI are both equal to 1.

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
 subset(data, HI == "1" | FI == "1" )
```

Comment: `data[data$HI == 1 & data$FI == 1, ]`

Comment: `subset(data, HI == 1 & FI == 1 )`

Comment: `|` means "or", you want `&` for "and"

Comment: It worked. Thank you akash87.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(df1,  HI == 1 & FI == 1)
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(HI == 1 , FI == 1)
```